# Unable to Install Facebook Duckling on Windows - Stack Exec Fails

Tags: windows, facebook, haskell, cmd, haskell-stack

I'm trying to [setup Facebook Duckling](https://github.com/facebook/duckling) on Windows 10.

When I execute: `stack exec duckling-example-exe` it produces the following error:

```
duckling-example-exe.EXE: /etc/zoneinfo/: getDirectoryContents:findFirstFile: does not exist (The system cannot find the path specified.)
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error since I followed [the recommendation on this GitHub thread](https://github.com/facebook/duckling/issues/412#issuecomment-550007731) which suggests replacing `"/usr/share/zoneinfo/"` in `Duckling/exe/ExampleMain.hs` with a link to a folder containing the `zoneinfo` files. You can see I replaced the path as suggested in the screenshot below:

[image]

I also tried adding a double slash as seen below - but it didn't help:

[image]

I tried with forward slash instead but this didn't help either:

[image]

Moreover, I don't understand where the path: `/etc/zoneinfo/` is coming from, if the path is no longer present in `ExampleMain.hs`? Where is the compiler pulling the path from?

Thanks!

Comment: In which directory are you running `stack exec duckling-example-exe`?

Comment: @Noughtmare `"C:\sr\snapshots\b65abc77\bin"` (that's where the file `duckling-example-exe` resides)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run `stack exec duckling-example-exe` in the directory where the `stack.yaml` and `project.yaml` files of the duckling source code is that you are trying to modify. Otherwise it will use the version of duckling from stackage without your changes.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much I've spent countless hours on this!

Comment: Can you explain why running `stack exec duckling-example-exe` inside `C:\sr\snapshots\b65abc77\bin` doesn't work - since this is where the executable is actually found? Just trying to understand the reasoning behind this.. Thanks